# Getting A non-numeric value encountered in PHP

Tags: php, math

I've been at this for over two weeks. The `+` seems to throw an non-numeric error and I can't figure out why.

```
<?php
define("number1", mt_rand(1,100));
define("number2", mt_rand(1,100));
echo(number1."<br>");
echo(number2);

echo("<br>".number1."x".number2."=".number1 * number2);
echo("<br>".number1."+".number2."=".number1 + number2);
echo("<br>".number1.":".number2."=".number1 / number2);
?>
```

And this is the error message:

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered on line 8

Comment: Put a parenthesis around your calculations when concatenating them to strings https://3v4l.org/1IdIa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `()`:

```
echo("<br>".number1."x".number2."=".(number1 * number2));
echo("<br>".number1."+".number2."=".(number1 + number2));
echo("<br>".number1.":".number2."=".(number1 / number2));
```

cause `.` means concatenation a string and `+ * /` cannot be used in this way.

*EDIT*:

- `"<br>".number1."x".number2."=".number1` has a **string** datatype
- **string** `* number2` means **string** `*` **numeric value** `=>` error